# Java - decode base64 - Illegal base64 character 1

Tags: java, base64

I have following data in a file:
[image]

I want to decode the UserData. On reading it as string `comment`, I'm doing following:

```
String[] split = comment.split("=");
if(split[0].equals("UserData")) {
    System.out.println(split[1]);
    byte[] callidArray = Arrays.copyOf(java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(split[1]), 9);
    System.out.println("UserData:" + Hex.encodeHexString(callidArray).toString());
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 1

What could be the reason?

Comment: you can try `getMimeDecoder()` instead of `getDecoder()` - the returned decoder does ignore invalid characters, but probably correctly dealing with SOH and BEL is recommened. Documentation extract: "*MIME: ... All line separators or other characters not found in the base64 alphabet table are ignored in decoding operation."

Answer (score 1):

The image suggests that the string you are trying to decode contains characters like SOH and BEL.  These are ASCII control characters, and will not ever appear in a Base64 encoded string.

(Base64 typically consists of letters, digits, and `+`, `\` and `=`.  There are some variant formats, but control characters are never included.)

This is confirmed by the exception message:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 1
```

The SOH character has ASCII code 1.

---

Conclusions:

1. You cannot decode that string as if it was Base64.   It won't work.
2. It *looks like* the string is not "encoded" at all ... in the normal sense of what "encoding" means in Java.
3. We can't advise you on what you *should* do with it without a clear explanation of:

   - where the (binary) data comes from,
   - what you expected it to contain, and
   - how you read the data and turned it into a Java `String` object: show us the code that did that!

Answer (score 0):

The UserData field in the picture in the question actually contains Bytes representation of Hexadecimal characters.

So, I don't need to decode Base64. I need to copy the string to a byte array and get equivalent hexadecimal characters of the byte array.

```
String[] split = comment.split("=");
if(split[0].equals("UserData")) {
    System.out.println(split[1]);
    byte[] callidArray = Arrays.copyOf(split[1].getBytes(), 9);
    System.out.println("UserData:" + Hex.encodeHexString(callidArray).toString());
}
```

Output:
`UserData:010a20077100000000`

Comment: Well yes ... but this could break if the way you got the `comment` string is sensitive to the platform text encoding scheme.  Embedding binary data in a "string" is kind of dodgy.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you, currently the string is not sensitive to the platform

Comment: You misunderstand me.  `new String(byte[])` is sensitive to the platform, because it depends on the platform dependent charset that is used to "decode" the bytes into a string.