# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character -1

Tags: java, android, arrays, base64

I am sending **byte[]** as encoded string through Android app. They way I am converting my **byte[]** is as follows (*Basically byte[] is the thumbscan/fingerscan image*): **Android**

```
byte[] imageData = m_left_enrollment_fmd(); // returns byte[] which is OK!
// Base64 belongs to android.util package
String forJson = Base64.encodeToString(imageData , Base64.DEFAULT);
```

And this is how I am decoding it on Server side (**Java**):

```
// Base64 belongs to java.util package
byte[] imageData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sqlJsonParams.optString("IMAGE_DATA"));
```

It generates following exception:

> ]] Root cause of ServletException.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character -1
>       at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
>       at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
>       at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
>       at org.skm.webresources.mobilehis.v2.Fingerprint.getByteArray(Fingerprint.java:470)
>       at org.skm.webresources.mobilehis.v2.Fingerprint.postFingerprint(Fingerprint.java:86)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

- **Question 1:** What I am doing wrong?
- **Question 2:** Is it the correct way to send byte[] in REST Service?

The Q&A I have seen so far are as follows:

- [Base 64 encode and decode example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code)
- [Base64: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584080/base64-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-character)
- [Java - decode base64 - Illegal base64 character 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533499/java-decode-base64-illegal-base64-character-1)

Answer (score 0):

I've sent images as multipart, maybe it will help:

```
ArrayList<MultipartBody.Part> list = new ArrayList<>();
        File photo = new File(image_uri);
        RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getMimeType(photo.getAbsolutePath())), photo);
        MultipartBody.Part partImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", photo.getName(), file);
        list.add(partImage);
        Call<Void> call = api.uploadMyImage(agreement, list, "@");
```

getMimeType():

```
public static String getMimeType(String url) {
        String type = null;
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
        if (extension != null){
            type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        }

        return type;
    }
```

to Base64:

```
public static String convertToBase64(String path) {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Looking at Android and Java's base64 API's, they both follow RFC 2045 but Java's version also follows RFC 4846 which has this small catch:

> MIME [4] is often used as a reference for base 64 encoding. 
>   However,    MIME does not define "base 64" per se, but rather a "base
>   64 Content-    Transfer-Encoding" for use within MIME.  As such, MIME
>   enforces a    limit on line length of base 64-encoded data to 76
>   characters.  MIME    inherits the encoding from Privacy Enhanced Mail
>   (PEM) [3], stating    that it is "virtually identical"; however, PEM
>   uses a line length of    64 characters.  The MIME and PEM limits are
>   both due to limits within    SMTP.
>
> Implementations MUST NOT add line feeds to base-encoded data unless
>   the specification referring to this document explicitly directs base
>   encoders to add line feeds after a specific number of characters.

Your Android's base64 encoder *is* doing a line feed after 76 characters while Java's encoder is expecting no line feeds at all. The way to handle this on Android's side is to use the no_wrap option and then it can be read by your Java server:

```
String forJson = Base64.encodeToString(imageData , Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Now it will read fine. This is the output of option Base64.DEFAULT:

```
ZI4069Ue3D5Ikbp93eJ/r6HQG3CPj3FxGE1SoywcgCuaJ0t5M/D79utSyF1Uf7C7NHdQ9fGuHQ2P\nJnNpsHAEpA==
```

versus the output of Base64.NO_WRAP:

```
ZI4069Ue3D5Ikbp93eJ/r6HQG3CPj3FxGE1SoywcgCuaJ0t5M/D79utSyF1Uf7C7NHdQ9fGuHQ2PJnNpsHAEpA==
```